# split items in python and attach some items

Tags: python, split

I want to split first item using `:` splitter but deny second one and etc.

I have a file with the following content:

```
# cat myfile
one:two
three:four
five:six:seven
eight:nine:ten
```

What I tried with python is:

```
with open('myfile','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            item1=word.split(':')[0]
            item2=word.split(':')[1:]
            print 'Item1: '+item1+' Item2: '+str(item2)
```

The result is:

```
Item1: one Item2: ['two']
Item1: three Item2: ['four']
Item1: five Item2: ['six', 'seven']
Item1: eight Item2: ['nine', 'ten', 'eleven']
```

But I want the follwing result:

```
Item1: one Item2: two
Item1: three Item2: four
Item1: five Item2: sixseven
Item1: eight Item2: nineteneleven
```

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Really this is not duplicated... please have a look on my question

Comment: Right, I missed that you wanted to just remove the `:` there. There are other duplicates for that though; want me to re-dupe?

Comment: Re-duped to the canonical 'list of strings' post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I don't think that this is really a dupe, there is no need to split all the words at all

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: so either it is a dupe of the 'split once' canonical (and you just use a `str.replace()` on the rest), or of the join one (joining the remaining elements). Pick one, all these steps are trivial.

Comment: @MartijnPieters,  trivial if you know how. The OP provided code, the output they got and the output they expected which is a lot more than alot of people do, while their question was related it is not an exact dupe of either of the questions it was marked as a dup of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split once and either `str.replace` or `str.translate` to remove the `:`, you should also split once and unpack:

```
In [6]: word,rest = s.split(":",1)

In [7]: rest = rest.translate(None,":")

In [8]: word,rest
Out[8]: ('eight', 'nineten')
```

using replace:

```
In [9]: s = "eight:nine:ten"
In [10]: word,rest = s.split(":",1)    
In [11]: rest = rest.replace(":","")    
In [12]: rest
Out[12]: 'nineten'
```

For python 3 you need to pass a dict to translate:

```
word, rest = s.split(":",1)
rest = rest.translate({ord(":"): ""})

print(word,rest)
```

You also don't need to iterate over the split line:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        word, rest = line.rstrip().split(":", 1)
        print('Item1: {} Item2: {}'.format(word,rest.translate(None,":"))
```

Output:

```
Item1: one Item2: two
Item1: three Item2: four
Item1: five Item2: sixseven
Item1: eight Item2: nineten
```

Answer (score 1):

You were going perfectly fine there, The one thing you missed was concatenating the split elements back to a string which is done by using `join`, you can change the separator to any other thing like `,` etc.

```
separator = ""
for line in f.split("\n"):
    for word in line.split():
        item1=word.split(':')[0]
        item2=word.split(':')[1:]
        print 'Item1: '+item1+' Item2: '+separator.join(item2)
```

Output:

```
Item1: one Item2: two
Item1: three Item2: four
Item1: five Item2: sixseven
Item1: eight Item2: nineten
```

Comment: Thank you, I want you to edit `item2=`. because I want use item1 and 2 to other functions